# background image for an <a> tag

Tags: html, css

please help me. I can't understand why my css code for background image doesn't work.

```css
.fb {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height:160px;
    display:block;
    background:transparent url('/images/social%20icons/normal/fb.png') center top no-repeat;
}

.fb:hover {
    background-image: url('/images/social%20icons/hover/fb.png');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fb"></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Try `../images/social%20icons/normal/fb.png`

Comment: And also one dot: `./images/social%20icons/normal/fb.png`. One dot if your image located in the same directory; two dots if it is located in the upper directory. And also try to remove the slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:   `../images/social%20icons/normal/fb.png`